# Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Tags: java, linux, flutter, ubuntu

I am trying to set up flutter with VS Code in Ubuntu. I have followed the installation guide and have installed the latest cmdline tools as required by the flutter doctor.

Now this is the output I get on running flutter doctor again

```
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
```

On running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I get the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled 
by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

I tried upgrading to Java 17 using `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk` and set up the environment variables but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you find a working solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 45):

I was able to resolve this issue on Windows 10 with these steps

[image: Install Android SDK Command-line Tools 8.0]

1. Using the Android Studio SDK manager, install Android SDK Command-line Tools 8.0. You may need to toggle the checkboxes highlighted in green to see the older versions like 8.0.
2. Using windows explorer, navigate to the `Sdk/cmdline-tools` folder. On my system it's located at `C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools`.
3. Rename the `8.0` folder to `latest`
4. Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It worked perfectly and solved my issue. You're a lifesaver! What I was missing was to select the 'show package details' otherwise the older version 8.0 was not visible.

Comment: same trick worked on macOS too, with the difference that the cmd line tools directory will be probably at `~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools`

Comment: You're a lifesaver, worked with me on windows 11 with version 10.0, latest version at the time of my comment is 11.0

Comment: finally found that is working for me. Thanks. Now the last problem is: Unable to find bundled Java version

Comment: @AgungSudrajat do you have the correct version of Java? (I can't remember which one is needed). If so, make sure it's correctly added to your PATH and SYSTEM VARIABLES.

Comment: Thank you, you are a rockstar. I did not even rename the `8.0` folder just deleted the `latest` folder, and it still worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me too.

Comment: I tried installing version 10.0 instead and without renaming the folder, but instead just removing the latest version. Worked for me at least. Thanks for this btw.

Comment: Also works with Unity 2022.3.19f1, when using custom Java/Android build tools

Answer (score 16):

Try this (for Mac)...

- Check Android SDK command-line Tools (latest)
- Check Android SDK command-line Tools 8.0
- Click Apply
- In Mac, go to `/Users/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools` and rename the `8.0` folder to `latest`.
- Run Flutter doctor again.

Comment: crazy, but it works

Comment: This worked for me!  Question: after running flutter doctor, do I restore the folder names?  Or just leave it (8.0 ==> latest).

Comment: This saved us from our blockage for weeks.

Comment: Also works with Unity 2022.3.19f1, when using custom Java/Android build tools

Answer (score 5):

Try This (For Windows) ...

- Uncheck Android SDK command-line Tools (latest)
- Check Android SDK command-line Tools 8.0
- Click Apply
- In Windows, go to
  “C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools” and
  rename the 8.0 folder to “latest”

Run Flutter doctor again.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. I only do the first three step and no need to rename the 8.0 folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fix it by removing the version installed (openjdk-11-jre and openjdk-11-jdk) and installing the newest one (openjdk-19-jre and openjdk-19-jdk).

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem but on Windows.
I solved it by completely uninstalling JDK, which searching on internet turned out to be a possible problem, and installing the latest version (20).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Apart from installing android sdk command line tool, I also have to upgrade my android studio to the latest to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Just update your platform tools, and command-line, and it should work

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you are suggesting is already explained in the other answers and in greater detail. Am I missing something?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).